# SQL Hide the nulls and join the results with the union

Tags: sql-server

How can I "join" the results and avoid duplicates? Like a Distinct function. I'm using Microsoft sql server studio

Query:

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Without modifying your query, you can group by the keys (`Contaa` and `NOMEe`) and take the `MAX()` of the nullable fields:

```
SELECT Contaa, NOMEe, MAX(cartCriados), MAX(TotQTD)
FROM
    (SELECT
         CLI.NUMERO as Contaa
        ,CLI.NOME as NOMEe
        ,COUNT(DISTINCT CA.Numero) as cartCriados
        ,NULL as TotQTD
    FROM Clientes as CLI
    LEFT JOIN Cartoes (nolock) as CA ON CA.Cliente=CLI.NUMERO
    LEFT JOIN VendasPOS_Cabecalhos (nolock) as VPC ON VPC.CLIENTE=CLI.NUMERO
    LEFT JOIN VendasPOS_Linhas (nolock) as VPL ON VPL.PRENUMERO=VPC.PRENUMERO
    WHERE CLI.NUMERO LIKE '2119%'
    GROUP BY CLI.NUMERO, CLI.NOME
    UNION ALL
    SELECT
         CLI.NUMERO as Contaa
        ,CLI.NOME as NOMEe
        ,NULL as cartCriados
        ,Sum(ln.qtd) as TotQTD
    from CB_VendasPOS (nolock) as VPCB
    right outer join VendasPOS_Linhas (nolock) as LN on (Ln.AutoReg=VPCB.AutoReg)
    join VendasPOS_Cabecalhos (nolock) as Cab ON (ln.prenumero=cab.prenumero)
    join Clientes (nolock) as Cli on Cli.numero=cab.cliente
    join VendasPOS_Turnos (nolock) as tu on (tu.codturnoauto=cab.codturnoauto)
    right outer join cartoes_mov (nolock) as cm on cm.prenumero=cab.prenumero
    where cab.data>='2015-01-01 00:00:00' and cab.data<='2015-01-30 00:00:00'
    and cm.tipocrt='D'
    group by CLI.NUMERO, cli.nome
    ORDER BY CLI.NUMERO) t
GROUP BY t.Contaa, t.NOMEe
```

You might be better off refactoring the query so it's just a single `SELECT` though...  I took a stab at it but it's difficult to say whether it actually would improve things enough to be worth it, especially without seeing some source data to test with.

Comment: This works. Thanks :) I was trying to do it in one select, but I can't seem to make it work

Comment: Yeah, I think you'd end up needing to join against subqueries, in which case this probably works about as well - or at least it's not worth the additional work it'd take if this is working well enough.